# unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

My code is resulting in the following error - why is this?

```
2 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Name\P4.java  [line: 44]
Error: C:\Users\Name\P4.java:44: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
File: C:\Users\Name\P4.java  [line: 46]
Error: C:\Users\Name\P4.java:46: exception java.io.FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
```

This is the code that is causing the error:

```
case Command.CMD_DO:
      NextCommand tmpReader;
      try {
       tmpReader = new NextCommand( c.getArg() );
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       tmpReader = null;
       System.out.println( "Unable to open file:");
       System.out.println( "   " + e.getMessage());
      }
```

The whole class is here:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Stack;


public class P4 {

 public static void main( String[] args ) {

  // Start off assuming we're reading from the console and create a stack
  // for storing "pushed" readers
  NextCommand reader = new NextCommand();
  Stack<NextCommand> cmdStack = new Stack<NextCommand>();

  // The command we get and a flag to indicate whether it's time to exit
  Command c;
  boolean userRequestsExit = false;

  // For storing the history. We keep track of the depth of the stack, too.
  // Note that we could just use cmdStack.size() but that's a Vector operation rather
  // than a "pure" stack operation, so for the sake of pedagogy, we won't...
  History h = new History();
  int nestingLevel = 0;

  do {
   // Get a command
   c = reader.get();
   h.add( c, nestingLevel );

   switch (c.getCommand()) {

   // Do nothing in response to a comment
     case Command.CMD_COMMENT:
      break;

   // DO filename. See if we can start a reader up from the file.
   // If not, then print an error and continue from where we left off.
   // If so, push the current reader onto a stack and continue with the new one
     case Command.CMD_DO:
      NextCommand tmpReader;
      try {
       tmpReader = new NextCommand( c.getArg() );
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       tmpReader = null;
       System.out.println( "Unable to open file:");
       System.out.println( "   " + e.getMessage());
      }
      // Success. Save current reader and switch to new one. We are
      // now nested one level deeper in DO files...
      if (tmpReader!=null) {
       cmdStack.push(reader);
       reader = tmpReader;
       nestingLevel++;
      }
      break;

   // DOC id "title" text 
     case Command.CMD_DOC:
    String[] docParts = c.getArg().split( "\"" );
    if (docParts.length != 3) {
     System.out.println( "ERROR: Invalid format: use DOC docid \"title\" text");
    }
    else {
     Document d = new Document( docParts[0].trim(),
              docParts[1].trim(),
              docParts[2].trim() );
     //Add document to database
     Database.documentList.add(d);
     if (d==null || d.getDocid()==null)
      System.out.println( "ERROR: Invalid DOC: " + d.getTitle() );
     else
      System.out.println( "Added document " + d.getDocid() );
    }
    break;

   // HISTORY
     case Command.CMD_HISTORY:
      System.out.println( h );
      break;

   // END. If the command-source stack is empty, we're done.
   // Otherwise, revert to the previous one and note that we are now
   // one level back up in the nesting of DO files.
     case Command.CMD_END:
    if (cmdStack.empty())
     userRequestsExit = true;
    else {
     reader = cmdStack.pop();
     nestingLevel--;
    }
    break;

   // Others
     default:
    System.out.println ("Only DOC, DO, HISTORY, and END commands work right now.");
   }
  } while (!userRequestsExit);

  // Courtesy exit message.
  System.out.println( "Thank you for playing." );
  System.out.println( "You processed " + h.numCommands()
       + " command"
       + (h.numCommands()==1 ? "" : "s")
       + " before you exited." );
 }

}
```

Here is the NextCommand class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class NextCommand implements NextCommandInterface  {

 private Scanner inStream;
 private boolean promptUser;
 private String nameOfFile;

 // Default constructor uses system input and requests prompting
 public NextCommand() {
  inStream = new Scanner( System.in );
  promptUser = true;
  nameOfFile = null;
 }

 // Alternate constructor to allow input from a file (no prompting)
 public NextCommand(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
  inStream = new Scanner( new File(filename));
  promptUser = false;
  nameOfFile = filename;
 }

 // Ask user for a command and process it to return a Command
 public Command get() {
  String inLine;

  // If we have no way to get input, pretend we hit the end
  if (inStream==null)
   return new Command( "END" );

  // Optionally prompt for the command
  if (promptUser)
   System.out.print( "Command? ");

  // Get a command (have to make sure EOF wasn't pressed)
  if (!inStream.hasNextLine())
   return new Command( "END" );

  inLine = inStream.nextLine();

  // Clean it up and return the results
  return new Command( inLine );

 }

 // A whimsical way to print this object out.
 public String toString() {
  if (nameOfFile == null)
   return "Commands being accepted from standard input";
  else
   return "Commands being accepted from " + nameOfFile;
 }
}
```

Comment: What is NextCommand? A custom class of yours?

Comment: Based on those warnings either the constructor for `NextCommand` or `c.getArg()` is throwing something called `FileNotFoundException`, not `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: NextCommand is a custom class, I can upload it if that would be helpful to you guys! Thanks! :)

Comment: @Cyrille Ka So the issue is with NextCommand?

Comment: No, I'm at loss, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Hmm, would you like me to upload any other classes?

Comment: @JasonBraucht any other thoughts? Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MouseEvent, what do you mean?

Comment: @MakMak The look-alike `FileNotFoundException` seemed the most likely culprit based on the error messages.  The next thing I'd try is feeding the `-verbose` flag to `javac` to get a better idea of what classes the compiler is loading.  Look for `FileNotFoundException` in the ouput.  Normally you would see something like `[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[c:\jdk1.7.0_11\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FileNotFoundException.class)]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation errors are saying that there are two versions of `FileNotFoundException` at play in `P4`.  There is `java.io.FileNotFoundException` which you have imported and are attempting to catch.  Then there is some other `FileNotFoundException` exception that (according to the compiler) is being thrown by the `NextCommand` constructor.

But that doesn't make sense ...

If the code is as you have shown us, and the compilation error is as you have shown us, then the only explanation I can think of is that *you need to recompile something*.

Specifically, you have changed the imports in `NextCommand` without recompiling it and then the `P4` class.

I suggest that you delete and then recompile all of your ".class" files.

---

<sup>The only other possibility is that you have defined a bogus version of `FileNotFoundException` in the same package as the two classes you showed us.  If you did that, your bogus class would take precedence over the real one.  But to make that "work" as an explanation, you'd also need to do the same thing with `Scanner` ... because the real `Scanner` constructor throws the real `FileNotFoundException` ... which is checked, and therefore has to be declared in the `NextCommand` constructor signature.  At this point, I'm going to dismiss this as "implausible".</sup>

Comment: I've tried recompiling everything and there is not other version of filenotFound defined...

Comment: Create an SSCCE so that other people can reproduce your problem; i.e. provide the minimum set of Java files that demonstrates your compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

Add throws `FileNotFoundException` to your `main()` method call, likes this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {
```

and then remove the try-catch block. Let me know how that goes.